# How to start Chrome in automation mode from command line?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, chrome

I am trying to find how to start Chrome as if it was started by `webdriver`, but manually from command line.

I was looking at this list of options, but couldn't find what I need.
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Note: I tried the `--enable-automation`, but it only displays the `chrome is being automated...` message. It still opens Chrome from my current profile in a new window.

Comment: what you mean by as if by webdriver , what is your criteria to confirm it is started by webdriver ?

Comment: The same way that would `new ChromeDriver()` start the browser. With the same options.
Aelxey's answer was what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you're doing `new ChromeDriver()` in your code, add these lines:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "D:\\chromedriver.log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
```

with your custom path to log file. Then open that file and find the line like:

`[INFO]: Launching chrome: ...`

There you will find the complete command line how driver starts your browser.